# How to copy a flatbuffer to other

Tags: c++, grpc, flatbuffers

I have a nested flatbuffer as following:

```
struct Flat_A {
    // s.t
}

struct Flat_B {
    // s.t
}

struct Flat_C {

    flata : Flat_A

    flatb : Flat_B
}
```

I want to create flatbuffer of flata : Flat_A first (in a difference flatbufferbuilder with its parent), and then copy this flatbuffer to the parent buffer(Flat_C).

I see function CopyTable, but it seem that it just copy to a NEW flatbuffer, not to an EXIST buffer like Flat_C.
Is there any way to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

`CopyTable` actually works for this purpose, it can copy from an existing buffer into a different builder. But it requires *reflection*, which is very clumsy, and I'd recommend against using it.

If you really can't construct C in one go, the best alternative is to change the `flata` field into `flata : [ubyte] (nested_flatbuffer: "Flat_A")`. You can copy the entire serialized bytes of A into `flata`, and you can then access it by getting the root of `flata` (there should be an accessor generated for you that does this automatically). This is actually almost as efficient as having a `Flat_A` type directly, since it is still accessing this nested buffer in place.

Comment: Hi @Aardappel, thank you for your answer.
if I change the flata field into flata : [ubyte], but still keep it as a field of flatc, is it possible if I copy flatbuffer of flata into without using CopyTable ?

Comment: Yes, it's just an array of bytes. You can use `memcpy`.